# Drupal 7 forms API: File upload

Tags: forms, file, drupal, file-upload, drupal-7

I've been following the form example 10 from the Drupal doc:
http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/group/form_example/7

Here goes the definition of my form:

```
function portal_upload_form($form, $form_state) {

    $form['file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => t('Choose a file'),
    );

    $form['document_submit_button'] = array(

      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('upload'), 
    );

    return $form;
}
```

And the form_submit hook:

```
function portal_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = $form_state['values']['file'];
        // ...
```

$file is 'empty' despite having set an input file with 777 permissions. I'm missing something and can't find what on my own...

Thanks!
J.

Comment: What do you mean with "having set an input file with 777 permissions". Where are these permissions set? If they are in your local pc, it's irrelevant, because server isn't reading directly from your pc.

Comment: Hi, the file I use for my test has permissions 777 on the local filesystem indeed. Given the browser needs to access the file (readonly), having at least read permission felt useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't answer the question of why the form doesn't provide with a file/url/... but it solves the whole upload issue:

```
function portal_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = $form_state['values']['file'];

    $validators = array();
    $file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, 'public://');
```

Comment: http://blog.ryantan.net/2011/04/drupal-7-handling-file-uploads/ yes it does helps

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other things to consider here:

1. file_save_upload() only will validate a default list of content types: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp
2. Be sure to name your first item in an associative array format i.e. `'#name' => 'files[img_1]',`

[file_save_upload() documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7), see the first comment for information on my second point.